# Swift WKWebView back navigation not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to load some web pages in my iOS app. In that case, I am getting an error in back press if I am using navigationDelegate to download files with WebView. If I am not using it, then it works fine but is unable to download files.

> 2023-08-04 15:26:01.154118+0530 WKWebViewDownloadHelper[6961:178029] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>

Code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }
    
    let extName:String = (navigationAction.request.url?.pathExtension)!
    if(checkFileType(type: extName)){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        decisionHandler(.download)           
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```